# Why can a method that takes varargs be optimised into a series of monomorphic calls only if it is static?

Tags: java, optimization, jvm, variadic-functions

At vJUG24, one of the topics was [JVM performance](https://virtualjug.com/vjug24-session-an-introduction-to-jvm-performance-by-rafael-winterhalter/).

Slides can be found [here](http://www.slideshare.net/RafaelWinterhalter/an-introduction-to-jvm-performance).

He had an example:

```
static void log(Object... args) {
    for(Object arg : args) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

which was called via (can't quite read the slide properly, but it's similar):

```
void doSomething() {
    log("foo", 4, new Object());
}
```

He said because it was a static method, it could be optimised by inlining it like this:

```
void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("foo");
    System.out.println(new Integer(4).toString());
    System.out.println(new Object().toString());
}
```

Why is it important that the log method is static for the JVM to make this optimisation?

Comment: How do you want to be sure that this method hasn't been overriden if it isn't `static`? (and it isn't `private` or `final` either)

Comment: @Tom: the JVM *knows* whether a method has been overridden. If knows every loaded class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either the presentation was not quite precise, or you did not get it right.

In fact, JVM **can** inline non-static methods, even with varargs. Moreover, it can eliminate allocation of corresponding `Object[]` array in certain cases. Unfortunately, it does not do this when a vararg method iterates over the array using `for` loop.

I made the following [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) benchmark to verify the theory and ran it with [GC profiler](http://java-performance.info/introduction-jmh-profilers/) (`-prof gc`).

```
package bench;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole;

public class VarArgs {

    @Benchmark
    public void inlineNonStatic(Blackhole bh) {
        inlineNonStaticVA(bh, "foo", 4, new Object());
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void inlineStatic(Blackhole bh) {
        inlineStaticVA(bh, "foo", 4, new Object());
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void loopNonStatic(Blackhole bh) {
        loopNonStaticVA(bh, "foo", 4, new Object());
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void loopStatic(Blackhole bh) {
        loopStaticVA(bh, "foo", 4, new Object());
    }

    public void inlineNonStaticVA(Blackhole bh, Object... args) {
        if (args.length > 0) bh.consume(args[0]);
        if (args.length > 1) bh.consume(args[1]);
        if (args.length > 2) bh.consume(args[2]);
        if (args.length > 3) bh.consume(args[3]);
    }

    public static void inlineStaticVA(Blackhole bh, Object... args) {
        if (args.length > 0) bh.consume(args[0]);
        if (args.length > 1) bh.consume(args[1]);
        if (args.length > 2) bh.consume(args[2]);
        if (args.length > 3) bh.consume(args[3]);
    }

    public void loopNonStaticVA(Blackhole bh, Object... args) {
        for (Object arg : args) {
            bh.consume(arg);
        }
    }

    public static void loopStaticVA(Blackhole bh, Object... args) {
        for (Object arg : args) {
            bh.consume(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

`-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintInlining` shows that all 4 variants are successfully inlined into the caller:

```
    @ 28   bench.VarArgs::inlineNonStaticVA (52 bytes)   inline (hot)
    @ 27   bench.VarArgs::inlineStaticVA (52 bytes)   inline (hot)
    @ 28   bench.VarArgs::loopNonStaticVA (35 bytes)   inline (hot)
    @ 27   bench.VarArgs::loopStaticVA (33 bytes)   inline (hot)
```

The results confirm that there is no performance difference between calling static vs. non-static methods.

```
Benchmark                Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
VarArgs.inlineNonStatic  avgt   20   9,606 ± 0,076  ns/op
VarArgs.inlineStatic     avgt   20   9,604 ± 0,040  ns/op
VarArgs.loopNonStatic    avgt   20  14,188 ± 0,154  ns/op
VarArgs.loopStatic       avgt   20  14,147 ± 0,059  ns/op
```

However, GC profiler indicates that vararg `Object[]` array is allocated for `loop*` methods, but not for `inline*` methods.

```
Benchmark                                    Mode  Cnt     Score     Error   Units
VarArgs.inlineNonStatic:·gc.alloc.rate.norm  avgt   20    16,000 ±   0,001    B/op
VarArgs.inlineStatic:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     avgt   20    16,000 ±   0,001    B/op
VarArgs.loopNonStatic:·gc.alloc.rate.norm    avgt   20    48,000 ±   0,001    B/op
VarArgs.loopStatic:·gc.alloc.rate.norm       avgt   20    48,000 ±   0,001    B/op
```

I guess, the original point was that static methods are always monomorphic. However, JVM can also inline polymorphic methods if there are not too many actual receivers in the particular call site.

Comment: I just checked the presentation; at no point does it say “because it is a static method”, in fact, it even describes the JVM’s capability of inlining non-`static` methods right before the example of the OP’s question.

Comment: Ah, it must have been me who misheard the presenter.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by eliminate the allocation of the Object[]? Does that mean the JVM optimises by changing the method signature to `log(String, Integer, Object)`, because it knows that's what's being called?

Comment: @Fodder A sort of. When `log` method is inlined, the escape analysis shows that `Object[]` array is short-lived in a local scope only, so JIT compiler replaces the array with several scalar values contained in this array, but `Object[]` is not allocated on the heap. Sometimes this optimization is also called 'on-stack allocation', though this is not very accurate. The correct name of this optimization is 'scalar replacement'.